# Cancel scrolling after user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

My webpage animates scrolling when users click on links to the same page. I want to cancel this animation as soon as the user tries to scroll (otherwise the user and the browser are fighting for control) – no matter whether with the mouse wheel, the keyboard or the scrollbar (or any other way – are there other ways of scrolling?). I managed to cancel the animation after the mouse wheel or keyboard are used, how do I get this working with the scrollbar?

Here is how my code looks for the keyboard:

```
$(document.documentElement).keydown( function (event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 38 || 40) stopScroll();
});

function stopScroll() {
    $("html, body").stop(true, false);
}
```

I also tried a more elegant way of doing this by using `scroll()`, the problem is that `scroll()` catches everything including the animated and automated scrolling. I could not think of any way to let it catch all scrolling except the animated scrolling.

Comment: Your code probably does not work because you code `keyCode == 38 || 40`. You should rather do something like `keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 40`. Your current code always passes the `if`-block since 40 is interpreted as `true`.

Comment: Ah, good to know! That mistake, however, doesn’t stop it from working, it simply makes scrolling stop no matter what key you press. By the way, is there some compact way of giving that if statement a list of keycodes? (I left quite a few out – page up/down, home/end – in what I copied in here to keep it short.) It seems like there must be a better way than to write `keyCode == number`six times.

Comment: You could e.g. provide an array of the keys in question and then use `$.inArray` to do the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need animation marker, something like this

```
$("html, body").stop(true, false).prop('animatedMark',0.0).animate({scrollTop : top, animatedMark: '+=1.0'})
```

Here is the code, the code was mix of GWT and javascript so moved it to js, not fully tested, please try it

```
var lastAnimatedMark=0.0;
function scrollToThis(top){
    // Select/ stop any previous animation / reset the mark to 0 
    // and finally animate the scroll and the mark
    $("html, body").stop(true, false).prop('animatedMark',0.0).
    animate({scrollTop : top, animatedMark: '+=1.0'}
    ,10000,function(){
        //We finished , nothing just clear the data         
        lastAnimatedMark=0.0;
        $("html, body").prop('animatedMark',0.0);
    });
}
//Gets the animatedMark value
function animatedMark() {
    var x=$("html, body").prop('animatedMark');
    if (x==undefined){
        $("html, body").prop('animatedMark', 0.0);
    }
    x=$("html, body").prop('animatedMark');
    return x;
};

//Kills the animation
function stopBodyAnimation() {
    lastAnimatedMark=0;
    $("html, body").stop(true, false);
}
//This should be hooked to window scroll event 
function scrolled(){
    //get current mark
    var currentAnimatedMark=animatedMark();         
    //mark must be more than zero (jQuery animation is on) & but 
    //because last=current , this is user interaction.
    if (currentAnimatedMark>0 && (lastAnimatedMark==currentAnimatedMark)) {
        //During Animation but the marks are the same ! 
        stopBodyAnimation();
        return;
    }

    lastAnimatedMark=currentAnimatedMark;    
}
```

Here is the blog about it

http://alaamurad.com/blog/#!canceling-jquery-animation-after-user-interaction

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jquery function that should do the trick:

```
function polite_scroll_to(val, duration, callback) {
    /* scrolls body to a value, without fighting the user if they
       try to scroll in the middle of the animation. */

    var auto_scroll = false;

    function stop_scroll() {
        if (!auto_scroll) {
            $("html, body").stop(true, false);
        }
    };
    $(window).on('scroll', stop_scroll);

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: val
    }, {
        duration: duration,
        step: function() {
            auto_scroll = true;
            $(window).one('scroll', function() {
                auto_scroll = false;
            });
        },
        complete: function() {
            callback && callback();
        },
        always: function() {
            $(window).off('scroll', stop_scroll);
        }
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant, but you could use a flag of some kind to detect what type of scrolling you're dealing with (animated or 'manual') and always kill it when it's animated. Here's an untested example:

```
var animatedScroll = false;

// you probably have a method looking something like this:
function animatedScrollTo(top) {
  // set flag to true
  animatedScroll = true;
  $('html').animate({
    scrollTop : top
  }, 'slow', function() {
    // reset flag after animation is completed
    animatedScroll = false;
  });
} 

function stopScroll() {
  if (animatedScroll) {
    $("html, body").stop(true, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I already tried this, using `stopscroll`like so: `$(document).scroll(stopScroll);`. The problem with this is that it also stops the animated scroll (after it moved one pixel). If I initiate `stopscroll`in another way I’m back to my problem of having to catch different kind of scrolling differently. (The addition of `animatedScroll` then doesn’t change anything functionally.)

Comment: Not sure if I follow — I thought you wanted to cancel the animated scroll?

Comment: The animated scroll stops even without any user interaction. Even if I don’t scroll myself, animated scrolling will stop.

Comment: Right idea here, but you need to set the flag for each tick of the `jquery.animate` call, not just once for the whole thing. I think you *should* be able to do this with the `step` option.