# Cancel scroll to top action on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I currently am using the following code to auto-scroll to the top on a callback from a swipe detect script. I want to add the ability to cancel the animation when the user clicks the screen during the animation.

```
$('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 300);
```

How would I accomplish this cancelation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel scrolling after user interaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160058/cancel-scrolling-after-user-interaction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `stop` method to stop the animation.  Make sure to pass `false` for the `jumpToEnd` parameter so the user isn't automatically taken to the top of the screen.

```
$(function() {
    //Substitute with whatever kicks off this scroll in your app.
    $('button').on('click', function(evt) {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 3000);

        evt.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(window).on('click', function(evt) {
        $('body,html').stop();
    });
});
```

**Live example** - http://jsfiddle.net/FcLbH/2/

**Edit** - Removed the parameters to `stop` per @AvL's comment.

Comment: Your example doesn't stop propagation when the button in the demo is clicked.  In your answer you don't pass ```false``` for ```jumpToEnd``` to keep the animation from automatically taking the user to the top of the screen.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but since there is nothing more in the queue we don't need the optional parameter `clearQueue`. And `jumpToEnd` is `false` by default. My jsfiddle works as requested...

Comment: You are correct about the parameters, in this case they're not necessary.  However, your jsFiddle still isn't working for me.  If I click the button and click somewhere else I don't stop scrolling.

Comment: Strange: It works on FF but not on Chrome... Must be a closure issue. I updated jsfiddle and my post. AND: `.stopPropagation()` is only needed in your example because you want to prevent the button to fire. ATLChris said something about a "a swipe detect script"...

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This worked best, but didn't work on some mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
$('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 3000).click(function() {
    $('body,html').stop();
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/DJ8Re/1/

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure about the click-detection, anyhow, this will stop the animation after 3 seconds:

```
$('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 6000);

setTimeout(function() { $('html,body').stop(); }, 3000);
```

For all the info on stop(): http://api.jquery.com/stop/